# No 404 for wrong URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having a strange problem.

When I run `http://local.tourplanner.com/category/educational/` it loads perfectly but when I use the following
`http://local.tourplanner.com/category/educational/category/educational/`, instead of presenting a 404 page, WordPress still loads the same page with correct content!!

Why is this? Can anybody please put some lights on this?

Comment: WordPress tries to help the end user by predicting the correct page to display if the page/uri actually requested doesn't exist. A 404 only shows if WP is unable to find a similarly named page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this only happens with category. I checked with post_type pages with similar URLs where I was taken back to homepage. This should at least happen with category pages as well. What do you think?

Comment: Thats how WP functions.

Comment: Please check your Permalink Structure. And also check that .htaccess is writable